# Is a Hausdorff separable topological space that is uniform and complete necessarily a Polish space?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is an Hausdorff separable topological space that is uniform and complete necessarily a Polish space ?

Comment: What do uniform and complete mean here? I guess the latter is Čech-complete, does the former mean the topology is induced by a uniformity?

Comment: How about $\{0,1\}^{2^\omega}$?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Perhaps “uniform and complete” means “induced by a complete uniformity”? That’s how I would read it.

Comment: Right, but with any reasonable interpretation your counterexample should work

Comment: @EmilJeřábek. Indeed, I mean "induced by a complete uniformity. Could you make an answer explaining how your counterexample works ?

Comment: A space with cardinality below the first uncountable measurable cardinal can be endowed with a complete uniformity if and only if it is realcompact. And any paracompact space can be endowed with a complete uniformity (and a space is paracompact if and only if it can be endowed with a supercomplete uniformity). These facts allow us to obtain counterexamples such as $\mathbb{Q},\beta\mathbb{N}$, the space of real numbers with the lower limit topology, the Sorgenfrey plane, and the product of up to continuumly many copies of the Sorgenfrey plane.

Comment: Functional analysis is awash with complete, separable, non metrisable locally convex spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple counterexample is $\{0,1\}^{2^\omega}$:

- It is a compact Hausdorff space, hence $T_{3\frac12}$, hence uniformizable, and any uniformity on a compact space is complete.
- It is separable by the Hewitt–Marczewski–Pondiczery theorem.
- It is not first-countable (it has character $2^\omega$), hence it is not metrizable.

Comment: And not just uniformizable, it's a topological group.

Answer (score 7):

Questions like these are often answerable by a search of the pi-Base (noting that every Hausdorff paracompact space is completely uniformizable): [https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%20hausdorff%2B%20separable%20%2B%20paracompact%2B%20~Metrizable](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%20hausdorff%2B%20separable%20%2B%20paracompact%2B%20%7EMetrizable)

- Weak topology on separable Hilbert space (see comments)
- Arens-Fort Space
- Sorgenfrey line
- Double arrow space
- Appert space
- Continuum-power of closed unit intervals
- Stone-Cech compactification of the integers
- Single ultrafilter topology
- Arens space

Comment: The weak topology of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space is not complete.

Comment: Thanks - opening an issue here (at an AIM workshop on math databases now so will look into this later...): https://github.com/pi-base/data/issues/477

Comment: So, does @JochenWengenroth remark imply that "every Hausdorff paracompact space is completely uniformizable" is incorrect?  Or does it mean that there is **some** complete uniform structure on $l^2$, compatible with the weak topology, other than the usual weak uniform structure?

Comment: I think "Stone-Cech compactification of the integers" is the best example, here.  It is compact, therefore completely uniformizable.  It has $\mathbb Z$ as a dense subset, therefore it it separable.  But it has power $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$, so it is not Polish.

Comment: I repeated the questionable formulation *the weak topology [...] is not complete* although I meant the *weak uniformity* of a Hilbert space. This uniformity is indeed incomplete. Whether there are complete uniformities generating the weak topology is a different property (which seems to be true for the weak topology of a separable Hilbert space). However, I did not find a reference for paracompactness.

Comment: The weak topology of a Hilbert (or reflexive Banach) space is $\sigma$-compact, hence Lindelöf and regular and thus paracompact.

Comment: So I believe the distinction here is the difference between a "complete uniformity", and the topological property of being "completely uniformizable".